# Ember Snapshot doesnt resolve belongsToRelationships

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, adapter

Im using ember 2.18 and i was trying to access nested api. 
when im trying to access that i override buildUrl in adapter.
i have two models programme and course which has a one to many relationship
of programme has many courses

issue im getting here is im trying to access belongsTo model's id which is programme id from course but it is not there.

> programme model

```
export default DS.Model.extend( {

  name:            DS.attr( 'string' ),
  code:            DS.attr( 'string' ),
  welcome:         DS.attr( 'string' ),
  startDate:       DS.attr( 'date' ),
  endDate:         DS.attr( 'date' ),
  published:       DS.attr( 'boolean' ),

  core_group:      DS.attr(),

  courses: DS.hasMany( 'course',{async: true}) });
```

> course model

```
export default DS.Model.extend( {

  uid: DS.attr( 'string' ),
  name: DS.attr( 'string' ),
  abbreviation: DS.attr( 'string' ),
  startDate: DS.attr( 'date' ),
  endDate: DS.attr( 'date' ),
  country: DS.attr( 'string' ),
  timezone: DS.attr( 'string' ),
  published: DS.attr( 'boolean' ),

  programme: DS.belongsTo( 'programme', { async: true} )
});
```

> adapter/mixin

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Mixin.create( {
  findRecord: function( store, type, id, snapshot ) {

    return this.ajax( this.buildURL( type.modelName, null, snapshot, 'findRecord' ), 'GET' );
  },

  buildURL: function( modelName, id, snapshot, requestType, query ) {

    var local_snapshot = snapshot;
    var url          = this._super( modelName, id, snapshot, requestType, query ),
        ancestorType = this.get( 'ancestorType' ),
        namespace    = this.get( 'namespace' ),
        ancestor,
        ancestorComponent,
        position;

    console.log(local_snapshot)
    // make a big assumption here, that requests will only be for a given parent,
    // not disparate parents
    if ( local_snapshot instanceof Array ) ancestor = local_snapshot[ 0 ].get( `${ancestorType}.id` );
    else ancestor = local_snapshot.get( `${ancestorType}.id` );

    position          = url.indexOf( namespace + '/' ) + namespace.length;
    ancestorComponent = '/' + Ember.String.pluralize( ancestorType );

    if ( ancestor ) ancestorComponent = ancestorComponent + `/${ancestor}`;

    url = [ url.slice( 0, position ), ancestorComponent, url.slice( position ) ].join( '' );

    return url;
  }


});
```

> adapter/course

```
import ApplicationAdapter from '../adapters/application';
import NestedMixin from '../adapters/mixins/nested';


export default ApplicationAdapter.extend(NestedMixin, {
  ancestorType: 'programme'
} );
```

error im getting is

> local_snapshot.get is not a function

when i look into model belongsToRelationships are empty means that it is not loaded correctly

Comment: [DS.Snapshot](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/v3.3.1/addon/-private/system/snapshot.js#L16) does not extend EmberObject and therefore does not have a `get` method.

Comment: thanks for the comment @jelhan. so how can i get the parent's model in there to find the id of the parent model?

Comment: [DS.Snapshot](https://emberjs.com/api/ember-data/3.3/classes/DS.Snapshot) provides `belongsTo` method to get a Snapshot of a related model. It provides `id` property to get the ID of the record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Jelhan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3167221/jelhan), i was manage to fix it using belongsTo method so the snapshot is called with {id:true} where i get the id of the parent relationship

```
snapshot.belongsTo(`${ancestorType}`,{id:true} );
```